# Sql Profiles in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am new bee in oracle,i am trying to understand sql profiles and implement them.
Here i am running sql advisor and got the below recommendations

1)Consider accepting the recommended SQL profile to use parallel execution for this statement.   99.7(benefit)
2)Consider accepting the recommended SQL profile.                                                95.88

I know the first option is parallel execution(which i can perform using parallel hints)
but when i implement the second option ,the explain plan shows plan same as parallel hint(first one).
Is the second recommended profile is also same as first one?
I tried to see degree used for this query in v$px_ tables,but i didn't get anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the method in [this article](http://kerryosborne.oracle-guy.com/2009/04/oracle-sql-profiles/) from Kerry Osborne to understand how your profiles work.

The short version is to accept a profile, find the new profile_name with `select * from dba_sql_profiles order by last_modified desc;`, and then run this query to find the
 hints:

```
select hint as outline_hints
from
(
  select
    p.name,
    p.signature,
    p.category,
    row_number() over
      (partition by sd.signature, sd.category order by sd.signature) row_num,
    extractValue(value(t), '/hint') hint
  from
    sys.sqlobj$data sd,
    dba_sql_profiles p,
    table(xmlsequence(extract(xmltype(sd.comp_data), '/outline_data/hint'))) t
  where sd.obj_type = 1
    and p.signature = sd.signature
    and p.category = sd.category
    and p.name like ('<add profile_name from above>')
)
order by row_num;
```

SQL Profiles are full of undocumented hints.  You can add your hints to the question but we may not be able to decipher them.  SQL Profiles are a neat idea but they are not very transparent.